# DFP inventory not showing ads

Tags: google-dfp

I have a bunch of DFP inventory spaces on my site. They all work, except for one. I can not figure out why.

In my header I have this:

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

<script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        /* other ad slots */
        googletag.defineSlot('/207676832/category-bottom-right', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1508175131469-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });

</script>
```

I have this on [the page](https://ugandaradionetwork.com/a/category.php?iCategory=7) (bottom of right column) in question:

```
<!-- /207676832/category-bottom-right -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1508175131469-0' style='height:250px; width:300px;'>
    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1508175131469-0'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

I have the inventory 'category-bottom-right' defined as a 300x250 ad space.

I have several ads of 300x250 pixels defined and connected to said ad space.

ghostery does return an issue, but does so for all other inventory as well, which show ads:

```
SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin "https://tpc.googlesyndication.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Pages on which ads *are* displayed (for me):

http://ugandaradionetwork.com/

https://ugandaradionetwork.com/story/who-releases-ugx-2-2-billion-for-marburg-emergency

**Update**:

I used DFP to regenerate the required tags/code and put the newly generated 
code in both the header and the place where I want the ad to show up. Yet, the Google console complains about "Overlay status: Not Displayed".

Screenshot of homepage, with ads:

[image]

Screenshot of category page, without ad:

[image]

Screenshot of code calling an ad on a category page:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code. Do you have a demo page where I could take a look at?
My first instinct is that there is something wrong with your configuration in DFP.

Comment: Thanks. The same property shows ads fine on other pages. Just this one doesn't seem to work. Adding a link now.

Comment: Could you also give me a link to a page where it does work? It doesn't work on any of the category pages nor on the homepage.
Edit: your page is tagged correctly and google doesn't throw any errors. The problem is definitely somewhere in your DFP set-up: line-items & creatives

Comment: Doesn't work on the homepage? It works on the homepage for me. :/ Adding links now.

Comment: Well, on the homepage and the story-page, you define the slot in the head, but nowhere in the body do you display it. Google throws 3 warnings, of which the following one: category-bottom-right: Warning,googletag.defineSlot was called without a corresponding DIV on the page.

Comment: Thanks! But... I'm getting some, the same, issues thrown by ghostery, on all pages. Nothing particular on the page on which the ads don't work, though. What browser do you use to get these errors? What errors do you get?

Comment: I'm just using Chrome. Add ?google_force_console=1 to the url (or & in case there is a ? already present in the url). That'll display the console of Google DFP and there you'll be able to see the warnings.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I still don't understand the problem, though. See update.

Comment: So, in order to show an ad, you need to do 2 things: 1. call "defineSlot" in the head of the page. And 2. you need to call the "display" in the body. On your homepage and category page, I see the "defineSlot" in the head, but I don't see the "display" in the body. That's why Google_force_console throws: Warning,googletag.defineSlot was called without a corresponding DIV on the page. You state you see an ad there, could you screenshot it and also screenshot the page_source of the Homepage where I should see the "display" call for category-bottom-right?

Comment: Added screenshots. Note that the homepage should not display 'category-bottom-right'. Only the category page should display 'category-bottom-right'.

Comment: Ah ok, if a certain page doesn't need certain slots, remove these slots from the head aswell. If you know you won't call "display" on the page, remove "defineSlot" from the head. In regards to the category-bottom-right: The code is implemented and executed correctly. DFP just doesn't return an ad for that position, leading us back to earlier: there is something configured incorrectly in DFP. Where you saw "Not Displayed", click on "Delivery Diagnostics" (of category-bottom-right). It'll open DFP and see what matched and what didn't.

Comment: If you want, feel free to give me access to your DFP account (read rights obviously and remove them afterwards). I'd understand if you don't want to do that as I'm a stranger, just saying it is an option if you'd like.

Comment: Well well. I was just lazy, putting all slots in the head at all times. Turns out that this seems to have been the source of my troubles: Only including the relevant slots on the relevant pages, the category page suddenly started showing ads. Thanks for the help! Do you want to write up an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Done! Thx for the debugging. It was very interesting :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution: only define slots which will be shown on the page. Google DFP reserves line-items/creative at the time of defining them.

So if you call home-top-right (300x250) and then category-bottom-right (300x250) and you have 1 line-item/creative that matches, Google DFP will reserve it for home-top-right (because that slot is defined first in the head). That means that category-bottom-right won't have a matching line-item/creative and therefor won't display anything

Thanks for the debugging via comments, I learned something new about DFP. Which actually makes a lot of sense and I should have known that ;-)